# Database save in PostgreSQL with Golang language

Tags: postgresql, go

I try to save data through PostgreSQL.
First of all, the update function works well when I do a receiving data and change some data what I want and then update this data in PostgreSQL. Here, I want to divide it into two functions. One is an update function that receives data and changes the data. The other one is the DatabaseUpdate function which writes data to the PostgreSQL (w.Write).

The origin Update function is

```
func UpdateTodo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var parsedRequest = &models.Todo{}
    utils.ParseBody(r, parsedRequest)
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    todoId := vars["todoId"]
    ID, err := strconv.ParseInt(todoId, 0, 0)
    // TODO: == 아닌가?? 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error while parsing")
    }
    todoDetails, db := models.GetTodoById(ID)
    if parsedRequest.Title != "" {
        todoDetails.Title = parsedRequest.Title
    }
    if parsedRequest.Description != "" {
        todoDetails.Description = parsedRequest.Description
    }
    if parsedRequest.Condition != bool(false) || bool(true) {
        todoDetails.Condition = parsedRequest.Condition
    }
    db.Save(&todoDetails)
    res, _ := json.Marshal(todoDetails)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(res)
}
```

I tried to change it into two functions; UpdateTodo and DatabaseUpdate

```
func UpdateTodo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var parsedRequest = &models.Todo{}
    utils.ParseBody(r, parsedRequest)
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    todoId, err := strconv.Atoi(vars["todoId"])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error while doing something")
    }

    convertIntTodoId := int64(todoId)
    todoDetails, _ := models.GetTodoById(convertIntTodoId)

    fmt.Println("(before)todoDetails: ", todoDetails)
    if parsedRequest.Title != "" {
        todoDetails.Title = parsedRequest.Title
    }
    if parsedRequest.Description != "" {
        todoDetails.Description = parsedRequest.Description
    }
    if parsedRequest.Condition != bool(false) || bool(true) {
        todoDetails.Condition = parsedRequest.Condition
    }
    fmt.Println("(after)todoDetails: ", todoDetails)

    // db.Save(&todoDetails)
    // res, _ := json.Marshal(todoDetails)
    // w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    // w.Write(res)
    
    DatabaseUpdate(&todoDetails, w)
}

func DatabaseUpdate(todoDetails interface{}, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    db := config.GetDB()
    db.Save(&todoDetails)
    res, _ := json.Marshal(todoDetails)
    fmt.Println("res: ", res)
    w.Write(res)
}
```

This is my app.go in config folder

```
package config

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var (
    db *gorm.DB
    err error
)

func Connet() {
    // Loading environment variables
    dialect := os.Getenv("DIALECT")
    host := os.Getenv("HOST")
    dbPort := os.Getenv("DBPORT")
    user := os.Getenv("USER")
    dbName := os.Getenv("NAME")
    password := os.Getenv("PASSWORD")
    // Database connection string
    dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable password=%s port=%s", host, user, dbName, password, dbPort)
    fmt.Println(dbURI)

    // Opening connection to database
    db, err = gorm.Open(dialect, dbURI)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Successfully connected to database!")
    }
    
}

func GetDB() *gorm.DB {
    return db
}
```

When I run the code, I got an error message < pq: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" >
db.Save(&todoDetails) <<<< this line.
When I check the console for todoDetails and res, I received the todoDetails data very well and I got res too. I am not sure why the error message said like that. Or, do I have to change another one?

Do I have to miss something or do something wrong?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I am not familiar with Gorm, but I am guessing that `db.Save(&todoDetails)` is at fault. The original code passes pointer to a struct to Save.  The new code passes a pointer to an interface that contains a pointer to a struct.  To make the new code match the old code, use  `db.Save(todoDetails)`.  Also, check the error returned from Save!

Comment: @Zombo First of all, thank you for your comment! Thank you so much, Zombo! It works very well! :) I think I need a rest. I am studying golang and PostgreSQL too much time today... I did kinda stupid.